# I need a button or a link which runs method from my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can create method in a controller and add routes for it. After that I'll be able to use it like that `<%= link_to "+", upvote_item_path(i) %>`, but now my methods are in the model.

How can I use them?

Should I create *.js.erb and write a function which runs by the button with onclick or there is another way?

Answer (score 1):

> I can create method in a controller and add routes for it

That is exactly how you invoke methods on your models. Your app needs to provide a route, controller and action which invokes methods on your models on behalf of the user.

Buttons and links have absolutely no direct access to your model layer. Your model layer and the client can *never* communicate directly. The client submits requests, which are routed to an action on a controller, and that action may manipulate your models in some way, and then render a result. Trying to allow clients to invoke methods on your model layer without going through an action is absolutely incorrect, and not at all supported by Rails.

Comment: Thank you. How can I call a model method in a controller?

Comment: I'm trying use gem Acts As Votable. There is a method .liked_by. How can I use it in a controller?